# NSView overlapping

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview

My cocoa app has a "dashboard" style layout.
When the app starts, the main window contains 6 views which display graphs. 
When I click on any part of the bottom most view, I have another NSView instance popping up 
as an annotation. The problem I run into is that is the pop up NSView is large enough dimension wise, 
the other views in the window overlap the pop up view. Currently, I do that with: 
[[self superview] addSubview:annotationView ]; where 'superview' is the window.
Im not sure why this would be the case, I have tried removing the the pop up view from the "view stack"
and making it change positions but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[[self window] contentView] insertView:popupView atIndex:0];
```

This will insert the view at the top level, if you still can't see it you will need to add a subview to the superview of the NSWindow's contentview.

Comment: try - (void)addSubview:(NSView *)aView positioned:(NSWindowOrderingMode)place relativeTo:(NSView *)otherView instead

Comment: I tried that line of code and it says no insertView atIndex method found. I tried the second method you advised withe the following code

Comment: sorry about that, insertView is something of UIView, the classes are so much alike that I didn't think NSView didn't have it

Comment: I tried adding that line of code but compiler says no insertView atInde method found. I tried the second way to do it which you point out in the following code [[self window] contentView] insertView:popupView atIndex:0]; but stil no luck even though it compiles ok.

Comment: use - (void)addSubview:(NSView *)aView positioned:(NSWindowOrderingMode)place relativeTo:(NSView *)otherView instead, it is the NSView equivalent of insertView:atIndex:

Comment: sorry for re posting comments, im trying to get the hang of commenting on this site and keep messing up.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html

Comment: I triend : 
try - (void)addSubview:(NSView *)aView positioned:(NSWindowOrderingMode)place relativeTo:(NSView *)otherView 
with no luck. I have also looked at the NSView class reference to fish out answers and havent been able to narrow down the problem

Answer (score 1):

If all the views are added as subviews of `[self superview]` then you must make sure that they do not overlap. Cocoa doesn’t guarantee correct behaviour in case there are overlapping sibling views.

If you want a popup view, consider using a child window instead. Since it’s a different window, the popup lies in a different view hierarchy, hence you won’t have the overlapping sibling views problem.

A good example of using child windows for additional information is [Matt Gemmell’s MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass).